# Unable to use memcache session in codeigniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I want to use memcache for sessions in codeigniter.i tried to use

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'memcached';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_save_path'] = '127.0.0.1:11211';
```

I got error: : Class 'Memcached' not found in 
as we have **memcache** on our server not **memcached**. I tried to use

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'memcache';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_save_path'] = '127.0.0.1:11211';
```

But it gives 
**Type: UnexpectedValueException
Message: Session: Configured driver 'memcache' was not found. Aborting.**

I know that  Memcache is installed and working on our server

```
$memcache      = new Memcache;
 $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only a Memcache**d** driver for `CI_Session`, you can't do without it.

Comment: is it possible for a server to have both memcache and memcached?

Comment: Sure, I don't see a reason why not.